# Turn text into hyperlink programmatically

Tags: hyperlink, phpspreadsheet

I have a multidimensional array and I save it in an excel file using PhpSpreadsheet:

```
   $this->active->fromArray($array, null, "A1");
```

The first column ($array[0]) contains URLs in string format (e. g. $array[0][0] = "https://stack.com/test").

I'd like to make so that every cell in column 0 becomes an hyperlink that links to page contained in the cell itself. What is the fastest way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

This is from phpSpreadsheet doc

**Change a cell into a clickable URL
You can make a cell a clickable URL by setting its hyperlink property:**

```
$spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('E26', 'www.phpexcel.net');
$spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getCell('E26')->getHyperlink()- 
>setUrl('https://www.example.com');
```

**If you want to make a hyperlink to another worksheet/cell, use the following code:**

```
$spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('E26', 'www.phpexcel.net');
$spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getCell('E26')->getHyperlink()- 
>setUrl("sheet://'Sheetname'!A1");
```

link to the page : Click [here](https://phpspreadsheet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/recipes/#:%7E:text=Cell%5CDataType%3A%3ATYPE_NUMERIC%0A%20%20%20%20)%3B-,Change%20a%20cell%20into%20a%20clickable%20URL,getCell(%27E26%27)%2D%3EgetHyperlink()%2D%3EsetUrl(%22sheet%3A//%27Sheetname%27!A1%22)%3B,-Setting%20Printer%20Options)!